# What is the probability that a random K-bit odd-number is prime?

Tags: probability, number-theory

Is it $e/K$?

In an experiment that created 1000 random RSA-2048 key-pairs, 2000 random 1024-bit primes were created.

It turned out that $727,709$ random candidates were generated, to create 2000 random 1024-bit-primes.

Each candidate was a random 1024-bit odd-number with MSB (Most significant bit) 1 and LSB (Least significant bit) 1.

$2000 / 727709$   is  approximately equal to $0.0027$.

$e / 1024$   is  approximately equal to $0.0026$.

Is this a coincidence?
Or, is the probability really  $e/K$?

Thanks,
  -Sreekanth

Comment: The probability of a random number $n$ being prime is $~\frac{1}{\ln{n}}$. If you say it's odd, then that increases the chances by a factor of $2$, hence the probability is $~\frac{2}{\ln{n}}$. If the number is $k$-bit long, then since $log_3{n}\leq\ln{n}\leq\log_2{n}=k$, the probability is a little over $\frac{2}{k}$.

Comment: But, in this setup, a K bit number is also greater than 2^(K-1). Does that matter?

Comment: Yes, I just gave a rough estimate in that comment. The answer below seems to be giving a tighter bound.

Comment: But the answer (shown below) doesn't consider the fact that a K-bit number is greater than 2^(K-1). Does it somehow cancel out in the end, or does it really matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is in the right direction. 
One often laxly says that the probability that $n$ is prime equals $\frac 1{\ln n}$. The more precise statement is the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem): There are approximately $\frac n{\ln n}$ primes below $n$ (and of course the really precise statement tells us what "approximately" means in this context).

Now in your setup, a $K$ bit number is a number $<2^K$, hence has "probability" $\frac1{\ln 2^K}=\frac1{K\ln 2}$. If we already exclude the even numbers, we improve this probability to $\frac2{K\ln 2}$. Numerically, we have $\frac2{\ln 2}=2.885\ldots$, which is not the same as $e=2.718\ldots$ but at least not too far off. So you only guessed the constant wrong.

Comment: But, in this setup, a K bit number is also greater than 2^(K-1). Does that matter?

Comment: From the Wikipedia entry on Bertrand's Postulate:  "the number of primes between n and 2n is roughly n/ln(n) when n is large".

In this set up, we have:  n = 2^(K-1).

So, in the end, we get the same answer, with the same constant:  2 / ln(2).  Thanks, -Sreekanth